# Get data from another component in the route tree

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-activatedroute

For example you have the components A, B and C and this route direction:

```
A -> B -> C
```

I can retrieve data from the previous component (got to C and get data from B)
with these lines:

Component C:

```
private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,

ngOnInit(): void {
        let B_ID = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['B_ID'];
}
```

But I want to retrieve data from the Component A:

Component C:

```
private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,

ngOnInit(): void {
       // let A_ID = this._activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.queryParams['A_ID'];
//Didnt retrieve the A ID
}
```

Comment: How do you want the route to look? you can't have query parameters inside sub routes like `componentA?data=something/componentB`. There is a lot of strategies for giving data. You can either use a service, `input` / `output` of components, or pass data in your routing config. Hard to tell which would be better for your case without more information

Comment: For complex routing i suggest using services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do communication between components you can easily do it using subjects.

For an example as you mentioned you have 3 components A,B,C 
then if u want get data in A component to C component you have to first make a service

ex-

```
 export class DatapassAtoCService{

  private messageCommand = new Subject<string>();
  Data$ = this.messageCommand.asObservable();

  invokeMessage(msg: string) {
    this.messageCommand.next(msg);
  }
}
```

in this example im passing value msg which is type string in component A to service this service uses a subject which is observable and it emit that value who have subscribe the this methord  in the service as shown below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatapassAtoCService} from '../services/message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-one',
  templateUrl: './component-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-one.component.css']
})
export class Acomponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private DataService: DatapassAtoCService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  string msg =This is pass to service;
  yourActionMethod() {
    this.DataService.invokeMessage(msg );
  }
}
```

then we can subscribe that service in C  component then that msg value is emmitted

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { DatapassAtoCService} from '../services/message.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-two',
  templateUrl: './component-two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-two.component.css']
})
export class CComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  messageSubscription: Subscription;
  message: string;

  constructor(private Dataservice: DatapassAtoCService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToMessageEvents();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.Dataservice.unsubscribe();
  }

  subscribeToMessageEvents() {
    this.messageSubscription = this.Dataservice.Data$.subscribe(
      (msg: string) => {
        this.message = msg;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

So as mention in the above code we can get that Acomponent msg value using the messageSubscription in Ccomponent

Answer (score 0):

You can get the router data by subscribing to router.events function. 
you can do something like this

```
this.router.events.subscribe(val => {

if (val instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
   console.log(val.state.root.queryParams);
    console.log( this.router.config)
}});
```

explore *val* Object and you can get values for particular route

Answer (score 0):

What i do is create a service to share information between components, for example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UtilsService {
  information:any;
.
.
.
```

Then you can save the information before leaving A in information variable from the created service.
Now you are able to read what is in information variable from the service in component C.

Remember to import the service and add it to the constructor of your component

```
import { UtilsService } from '../../providers/utils.service';
```

_

```
constructor(
    private utilsSvc: UtilsService,
  ) {
```

You can access it by `this.utilsSvc.information`.